# Can you run JUNG graph visualization in an Android Application?

Tags: android, jung, graph-visualization

I am a newbie when it comes to android graphics. I was implementing some code into a machine learning project I am working on. I wanted to be able to load the data into JUNG and have it visualize a 3 dimensional graph inside an android application.

Is this possible?

What recommended sources should I look into regarding this?

Should I be implementing this into an application? [VisualizationViewer Link](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/VisualizationViewer.html)

Comment: You can use JUNG library but there are a few Java classes are not available on Android SDK: Swing, JMX, etc. Probably you need to filter these classes using ProGuard. If you don't use any of JUNG's Swing components, your app will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, if you must. Steps to include JUNG into your Android app

1. Copy the jung library file into libs folder
2. Select jar file -> right click -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path
3. Clean the project Project-> Clean -> select your project -> ok

But there are better, and more popular Android graph libraries

1. [ChartDroid](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/wiki/Screenshots)
2. [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/)
3. [AChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)
4. [WilliamChart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart)

I would suggest using these instead, as they have a much larger community, which means better support.

Some good examples of 3D plots are given [here](https://github.com/vaibhav-jani/AndroidGraphExperiments)

[EDIT]

*OP mentioned that JUNG is a Java Swing Library.*

Apparently there isn't any program out there that I know of to convert Swing to XML. The Java code and the android code are very similar. Once you get the ui functions of the android app down your Java code can be easily imported.

Comment: Are there any 3 dimensional graphing libraries for android? I noticed all of those are for 2 dimensional raphs

Comment: Updated answer. Added now

Comment: @RishiDua FYI, JUNG is a mathematical "network graph" library based on the [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), not a charting library. All visualization components of JUNG are using Java SWING which is not supported on Android.

Comment: Updated answer once again!